# Websphere Portal version 7 gives an Error 404 when trying to open the console page

Tags: websphere-portal

I've installed Portal version 7 and i've got a default profile wp_profile while installation. But, when I'm trying to open the console page by typing the host-name:10039/wps/portal I'm getting an error as

Error 404: There is no content available.

What are possible options to get this issue resolved. If it's a configuration issue, please tell me what should be changed.

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs?

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong, but as I remember WebSphere Portal 7 have different default port than 10039. I think you can try 10040 or 10041.

Anyway you can check it different ways:

1) WAS Console > Application servers > WebSphere_Portal > Ports -> WC_defaulthost

2) Go to ..\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\config\cells\wpsCell\nodes\wpsNode\serverindex.xml and lookup for WC_defaulthost